# 'IServiceCollection' Does Not Contain A Definition For 'AddIdentity' In ASP.NET Core 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I am attempting to register Identity with a custom class that inherits from `IdentityUser`, however, when I try, I get the following error:

> cs1061

The following package is installed:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

This is my code:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddDefaultIdentity` instead of `AddIdentity`.
For more info: [check MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Or You can check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentity?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and use `AddIdentity<TUser,TRole>(IServiceCollection)`

Comment: I can, however, that leads to other issues. 

such as with the following codeblock: 

    public Home( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) => _userManager = userManager;

Home gives the cs0051 error.

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` & `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` package?

Comment: Yes, I have installed both, and just double-checked to make sure.

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` you have this package?

Comment: I just installed it, but the errors are still occurring.

Comment: It uses `AddIdentity<TUser,TRole>(IServiceCollection)`, you need to assign User and Role.

Comment: Okay, so the cs1061 error went away when I modified the following code to: 

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityUserRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


However I am still getting the cs0051 error here: 

public Home( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) => _userManager = userManager;

Comment: Can you please show the exact error ?

Comment: public Home(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) => _userManager = userManager;

CS0051: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'UserManage<ApplicationUser>' is less accessible than method 'Home.Home(UserManager<ApplicationUser>)'

Comment: Make sure this class is `public` and accessible.

Comment: Which class specifically?

Comment: I think this  should be `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` instead of `UserManage<ApplicationUser>`. It should be Manager not Manage.

Comment: It is, I apologize, it was a typo on my part. I had to hand-type the error.

Comment: Fixed the CS0051 error. Forgot a 'public' before 'class'.

Comment: It is resolved now, right?

Comment: Possibly. There is another error, I think opening a new question would be best. 

Thank you for the help!